# Angular Calling Self-Signed External Services

Tags: angularjs, angular, user-interface, ssl, ssl-certificate

In Angular is there a way to call external self-signed HTTPS services either by passing or by attaching the certificate used by the external service? I'm not familiar with the Angular but there is an method in cURL library where you can attach the signed certificate to avoid CA not trusted error

```
curl --cacert external.service.self-signed.certificate.crt --location --request GET 'https://external.services/'
```

If not Angular UI keep generating an error indicating the external service CA is not authorized

```
GET https://external.services/ net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
```

Comment: Angular is just javascript, can you achieve the same thing in plain javascript?

Comment: @AviadP. This where I need some help. Is it possible to call an external HTTPS end-point with self-signed certificate ? Without installing the certificate to each browser manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot achieve it using angular or a plain javascript as it would be a huge security breach.

You should add that self signed certificate to trusted list by your browser or operation system.

One of intermediate fix could be just follow that link in a browser, then it'll show a warning screen (because the cert is invalid), you accept it and for a limited amount of time that resource should be available for your javascript code.